# SQL recurring date list with Start Date, End Date Off days & Off Intervals

Tags: sql-server-2012

Looking to fill a table (SQL Server) given the following data: start & end date (date), off days (varchar), frequency for repeating interval (int)

StartData - 04/1/2018, EndData - 04/30/2018, offdays = 'Thrusday', freq = 1

Output:

```
04/01/2019
04/02/2019
04/03/2019
04/04/2019 -> Skip every thrusday
04/05/2019
04/06/2019
04/07/2019
** Skip 7 days
04/15/2019
04/16/2019
04/17/2019
04/18/2019 -> Skip every thrusday
04/19/2019
04/20/2019
04/21/2019
** Skip 7 days
04/29/2019
04/30/2019
```

Comment: Your expected output says "Skip 7 days," but I am seeing a 10 day interim in your date sequence.  Can you explain this?

Comment: @Tim you were right. I have updated my output result. Please see it basically i want list of recurring date on the basis of recurrence rule. Like: FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,FR;INTERVAL=1

Answer (score 1):

If open to a Table-Valued (helper) Function, consider the following

**Example**

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2018-04-01'
Declare @Date2 date = '2018-04-30'
Declare @Freq  int  =  1
Declare @OffDays varchar(50) = 'Thursday'  -- Try 'Saturday,Sunday'


Select * 
 From  [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date](@Date1,@Date2,'DD',@Freq) 
 Where charindex(DateName(WEEKDAY,RetVal),@OffDays)=0
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```

Comment: Thanks, i want achieved something different like:
Interval means skip complete 7 days after 7 days. 
For example: Mon - Sun one week then next week skip then shown again Mon - Sun dates again.